# How to add array contents to the HTML in AngularJS when the user selects an option

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I've been struggling with a programming task in AngularJS. I've got the basics sorted, but I don't seem to understand a particular part, and I don't know which Angular command/directive to use.

I'm supposed to add the fish (which is contained within an array) the user chooses (from the form) to the HTML, and keep adding more fish as they choose more fish, and remove them when they want (Should I use ng-model?).

So far I have the following:

HTML

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
        <html ng-app = "fishSaver">
        <head>
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
            <script src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.5.8/angular.min.js"></script>
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
        </head>
        <body ng-controller= "fishController as fishC">
            <!--- Choose fish from dropdown--->
        <div ng-controller = "fishController as fishCtrl">
            <form >
            Choose a fish
                <select ng-model= "theFishes">
                    <option value="Gold" ng-model = "gold">Gold Fish</option>
                    <option value="Angel" ng-model = "angel">Angel Fish</option>
                    <option value="Babel" ng-model = "babel">Babel fish</option>
                </select><br>
            </form> 
        <br>
            <div class = "col-sm-6 col-md-3" ng-model = "fishProfiles">
            {{fishCtrl.fishProfiles}}
            </div>  

        </div>


        </div>
        </body>
        </html>
```

AngularJS:

```
     (function(){
        var app = angular. module('fishSaver', [])


        // fish controller
        app.controller('fishController', function(){

        var vm = this;

        // define a new profile 
        vm.fishProfiles = fishArray;

        });


        // JSON object

        var fishArray = [

            {name: 'Gold Fish', 
            weight: 0.1,
            images:'images/gold.jpg'},

            {name: 'Angel Fish',
            weight: 0.2,
            images:'images/angel.jpg'},

            {name: 'Babel Fish',
            weight: 0.3,
            images:'images/babel.jpg'}


        ]
        })();
```

thanks

Comment: you said choose more fish means are you providing any check boxes or what ? can you be some what specific regarding the question.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**:

**html:**

```
<body ng-app = "fishSaver" ng-controller= "fishController as fishC">
    <!--- Choose fish from dropdown--->
<div ng-controller = "fishController as fishCtrl">
    <form >
    Choose a fish
        <select ng-model= "theFishes" ng-change="fishCtrl.selectedFish(theFishes)">
            <option value="Gold" >Gold Fish</option>
            <option value="Angel">Angel Fish</option>
            <option value="Babel">Babel fish</option>
        </select><br>
    </form> 
<br>
    <div class = "col-sm-6 col-md-3" ng-model = "fishProfiles">
    {{fishCtrl.fishProfiles}}


    </div>  

  <hr>
  <h3>my list</h3>
    {{fishCtrl.fishList}}

</div>


</div>
```

javascript:

```
  (function(){
        var app = angular. module('fishSaver', [])

        // fish controller
        app.controller('fishController', function(){

        var vm = this;

        // define a new profile 
        vm.fishProfiles = fishArray;
         vm.fishList = [];

       vm.selectedFish = function(fish){

         vm.fishList.push({'name':fish})
    }
        });




        // JSON object

        var fishArray = [

            {name: 'Gold Fish', 
            weight: 0.1,
            images:'images/gold.jpg'},

            {name: 'Angel Fish',
            weight: 0.2,
            images:'images/angel.jpg'},

            {name: 'Babel Fish',
            weight: 0.3,
            images:'images/babel.jpg'}


        ]
        })();
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what your asking is it just how to display the fish in the array and provide a mechanism to remove them?